# Which weapon has the slowest reload speed?

Tags: borderlands-2

[Zer0 the Assassin](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0) has a skill called [Rising Sh0t](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Rising_Sh0t).

> Faster weapons [can] gain stacks more quickly, but slower weapons retain stacks for a longer period of time.

I've learned that switching weapons can change the decay rate. So, to minimize stack decay, which weapon or weapons have the slowest reload speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Hive has the slowest reload speed of all weapons in Borderlands 2.

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hive

That is, one with either Bandit or Torgue grip and non-Tediore sight. Torgue grip is better (per saving ammo (shooting twice per magazine either way), more damage, and more accuracy).